# downsampling rate with movement data (first point equal from the original matrix)

Tags: matlab

I was wondering if the procedure applied trying to download the sample rate was the appropriate as follows the instruction: y = downsample(x,n)

```
downsamp_rate = 40;
downsampled_data = downsample(X,downsamp_rate);
```

.. because my doubt relays in why the first column from both matrices is exactly the same (the original matrix and the sample donwloaded)maintaining the same data....

then the other data have already transformed to a lower sample rate.

Thank you so much!

Best!

edited: Sample data. I pasted the data but I can upload de .mat files.

Original data.

```
  column 1             column 2          column 3
-0,593600000000000  -0,592699999999996  -0,591899999999995
2,42180000000000    2,41010000000000    2,40360000000000
1,78550000000000    1,79020000000000    1,79530000000000
-1,30590000000000   -1,31520000000000   -1,31530000000000
-0,707800000000003  -0,712699999999999  -0,727700000000003
-0,986500000000001  -0,996000000000002  -1,00460000000000
-0,989699999999999  -0,989699999999999  -0,989699999999999
1,23500000000000    1,22970000000000    1,21880000000000
0,122899999999998   0,127899999999997   0,128899999999998
0,938300000000003   0,937500000000002   0,936200000000004
0,248600000000004   0,248500000000002   0,248700000000002
-0,381499999999996  -0,393199999999999  -0,393699999999997
0,294099999999997   0,279299999999999   0,271299999999997
-0,223200000000001  -0,223699999999999  -0,227299999999997
0,0879999999999992  0,117300000000004   0,122500000000003
-0,167899999999999  -0,170999999999999  -0,174800000000003
-0,687499999999996  -0,697199999999998  -0,701600000000002
-0,681700000000002  -0,682200000000000  -0,683000000000000
1,19659999999999    1,19670000000000    1,19490000000000
-0,565500000000008  -0,565199999999999  -0,557400000000008
```

Downsampled data

```
column 1               column 2            column 3
    -0,593600000000000  0,821900000000003   0,936300000000001
    2,42180000000000    1,14610000000000    -0,255400000000000
    1,78550000000000    2,86550000000000    3,66890000000000
    -1,30590000000000   7,01950000000000    12,9564000000000
    -0,707800000000003  3,05920000000000    0,852999999999998
    -0,986500000000001  -0,372200000000000  -0,951000000000002
    -0,989699999999999  -0,988000000000000  -1,21730000000000
    1,23500000000000    5,79700000000000    3,40880000000000
    0,122899999999998   5,32230000000000    5,19260000000000
    0,938300000000003   4,88130000000000    7,55900000000000
    0,248600000000004   4,79290000000000    2,96620000000000
    -0,381499999999996  -0,400000000000000  0,641500000000000
    0,294099999999997   -0,131400000000004  -1,20040000000000
    -0,223200000000001  1,49610000000000    1,59030000000000
    0,0879999999999992  0,418700000000000   -0,0114999999999976
    -0,167899999999999  0,0149999999999983  -0,857500000000000
    -0,687499999999996  -0,593100000000002  0,119700000000000
    -0,681700000000002  -0,170000000000003  0,126799999999999
    1,19659999999999    1,17670000000000    1,15780000000000
    -0,565500000000008  8,89019999999999    6,58569999999999
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Be great if you couple provide us with a sample of the data you are using.

Comment: I supposed that is the main function which maintains the initial values from the first column, but I'm still wondering why.... 

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible for your output is a periodic input signal with a period length of `downsamp_rate-1`. To give a short demonstration:

```
>> X=repmat(1:39,1,10);
>> downsampled_data = downsample(X,downsamp_rate);
>> downsampled_data

downsampled_data =

  Columns 1 through 9

     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9

  Column 10

    10
```

Thus, take a look at your rows 40,41,42. I assume the first value is identical to your row 1,2,3

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, what do you mean with values identical for rows 40,41,42 & 1,2,3...

and I`m still confused, it is normal to have the same values in the original and the sampled matrix (just the first column)..

Best!

Comment: When your original signal is periodic like the example I provided, you can end up with an identical signal when downsampling.